# inserting data including slashes into mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some small data with slashes in it.

I am doing a csv import with over 2000 lines. I am looping through each one and it goes fine but when I have slashes in the text the whole string wont import. I dont get any errors. The data just doesn't show up in the database.

Sample text would be "Barr/Massive"

How can I make it so mysql doesn't strip the slash.

Comment: it would be helpful if you included your full load data statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bind parameters, don't insert the data directly into your SQL.

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES ($name)
```

versus

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (?)
```

I'm assuming you're using some kind of PHP or Perl script for this. Otherwise, phpMyAdmin has a CSV import.